# angular y google chart

Tags: .net, angular4

soy nuevo en Angular e intento integrarlo con VS2015 junto con el chart de Google. A partir del siguente [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044101/how-do-i-put-a-google-chart-in-angular-4) pude avanzar, pero no se reenderiza como espero.

Cuando defino la siguente ruta 
`const appRoutes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: ChartComponent },`

funciona perfectamente, pero si intento acceder `{ path: 'report', component: ChartComponent }`. no tuve suerte. Alguna sugerencia y/o guia, por favor? Desde ya muchas gracias.

ChartComponent

```js
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleChartComponent} from '../chart/googlechart.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-chart',
    template: `
   <div id="barchart_material" style="width: 700px; height: 500px;"></div>
  `,
    styles: []
})
export class ChartComponent  extends GoogleChartComponent {
    private options: any;
    private data: any;
    private chart: any;
     //constructor() {
     //  //super();
     //  console.log('');
     //}
    drawGraph() {
        console.log('Drawing Bitcoin Graph');
        this.data = this.createDataTable([
            ['Price', 'Coinbase', 'Bitfinex', 'Poloniex', 'Kraken'],
            ['*', 1000, 400, 200, 500]
        ]);

        this.options = {
            chart: {
                title: 'Bitcoin Price',
                subtitle: 'Real time price data across exchanges',
            },
            bars: 'vertical' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
        };

        this.chart = this.createBarChart(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));
        this.chart.draw(this.data, this.options);
    }
}
```

GoogleChartComponent

```js
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
declare var google: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'chart'
})

export class GoogleChartComponent implements OnInit {
    private static googleLoaded: any;
    constructor() {
        console.log('Here is GoogleChartComponent');
    }

    getGoogle() {
        return google;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('ngOnInit');
        if (!GoogleChartComponent.googleLoaded) {
            GoogleChartComponent.googleLoaded = true;
            google.charts.load('current', {
                'packages': ['corechart']
            });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => this.drawGraph());
        }
    }

    drawGraph() {
        console.log('DrawGraph base class!!!! ');
    }

    createBarChart(element: any): any {
        return new google.visualization.BarChart(element);
    }

    createDataTable(array: any[]): any {
        return google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);
    }
}
```

AppModule

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import {ChartComponent } from './chart/report.component';
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from './not-found/PageNotFoundComponent'
import {AutorizacionService} from './services/authentication.service';
import {SignalRService} from './services/signalr.service';
import {AuthGuard} from './guard/guard.service';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
    //{ path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: ReportComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }, //canActivate: [AuthGuard]  }
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
    { path: 'report', component: ChartComponent },


];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    providers: [AutorizacionService, AuthGuard, SignalRService],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent,
        ChartComponent 
        
    ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor() {
        console.log('appmodule')
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola fer, Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Por favor, añade tu objeto Routes completo a la pregunta o será complicado ver el fallo. En cualquier caso te aconsejo leer esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hola pablo, muchas gracias por tu rta, ahora edito para ingresar mi codigo del app.module.ts

Comment: Qué tipo de error te da? No sale nada en la pantalla? Hay algún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: el error seria que no encuentra el path { path: 'report'... , en consola no me da ningún error y me redirecciona al PageNotFoundComponent hice pruebas como comentaba de cambiar el path al inicio y alli funciona sin problemas el componente, al parecer es la ruta..

Comment: Qué URLs usas? Tienes que intentar poner todos los datos posibles en la pregunta para que tengamos claro el escenario

Comment: mil disculpas, no tuve suerte en insertar codigo, aun estoy conociendo la plataforma. En cuanto a Urls, te refieres a los Component? aun sigo sin entender como funciona acabo de cambiar el component del path login y funciona sin problemas. el problema esta en definir un path particular y/o lugar de donde invocarlo

Comment: bueno, pude hacerlo funcionar cambiando a la ultima posición el PageNotFoundComponent, Cuando habilite el modo ` debuggin { enableTracing: true } ` pude ver que aparentemente el RoutesRecognized no resolvia el path seteado. Es asi? el orden influye?

Answer (score 0):

bueno, pude hacerlo funcionar cambiando a la ultima posición el PageNotFoundComponen. Fue de gran ayuda habilitar modo debuggin en el Route `{ enableTracing: true }`.

El Route quedo de la siguiente manera

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }, //canActivate: [AuthGuard]  }
{ path: 'report', component: ChartComponent },
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
```

];